# Show that the connected components of a graph induced by the symmetric difference of two perfect matchings are a cycle.

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

Let $G$ a graph and $M_1 , M_2$ not equal perfect matchings, show that every connected component of $G[M_1 \triangle M_2]$ is a cycle. Where $G[M_1 \triangle M_2]$ is the induced graph by the symmetric difference of these two perfect matchings.

What I've got so far is that since $M_1, M_2$ are not equal then $M_1 \triangle M_2 \neq \emptyset$ and $G$ has an even number of vertices, also that the induced graph has the same number of vertices than $G$.

Should I suppose a contradiction taking a connected component? 
Any hints?

Comment: Look at the degrees of the vertices in the induced subgraph.

Comment: They're all even?

Comment: Can there be a vertex of degree 4?

Answer (score 1):

Take the multigraph union $G[M_1\cup M_2]$ of the two matchings $M_1$ and $M_2$.

Since a perfect matching saturates all vertices, the multigraph union results in each vertex having degree 2.

It is a [well-known result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3321802/prove-that-a-connected-simple-graph-where-every-vertex-has-a-degree-of-2-is-a-cy) that if every vertex in a connected component is of degree 2, the component is a cycle. Therefore, every component in this graph is a cycle.

Next, we note that $G[M_1 \triangle M_2]$ can be obtained by removing edges of multiplicity 2 from $G[M_1\cup M_2]$.

The result follows.

Comment: Aren't the components cycles **and isolated vertices**? A simple graph with one vertex and no edges is not a cycle.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear, I will reword the answer to make it better. 

What I did was take the **multigraph** (not simple) union of the two matchings and thus there will be no isolated vertices, but instead cycles that loops between two vertices where the isolated vertices are in the symmetric difference graph. 

The following paragraph is a note that removing edges with multiplicity gives exactly the symmetric difference graph.

Comment: It's admittedly a roundabout way of approaching the question, and can be bypassed completely.

Comment: I understood what you were doing. I was thinking that the original question was wrong, because in my hasty reading I overlooked that the OP was talking about the induced subgraph $G[M_1\Delta M_2]$ and was thinking of the spanning subgraph with edge set $M_1\Delta M_2$. My bad.